# Convert Access Transform/Pivot functions to mssql with multiple aggregates (concatenated in one header)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Can somebody help me to write this code in mssql? I read multiple answers on dynamic pivoting in mssql, but can not apply it to my particular code, since I don't know how to pivot multiple aggregates that are concatenated in one header.

Here is the code in Access:

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Sales.Tons) AS SumOfTonsSELECT     Sales.ID_SaleDest 
FROM       (QualPack 
INNER JOIN (Groups 
INNER JOIN (Customers 
INNER JOIN SaleDest 
ON         Customers.ID_Customer = SaleDest.ID_Customer) 
ON         Groups.ID_Group = SaleDest.ID_Group) 
ON         QualPack.ID_QualPack = SaleDest.ID_QualPack) 
INNER JOIN Sales 
ON         SaleDest.ID_SaleDest = Sales.ID_SaleDest 
WHERE      ((( 
                                            Year([Date_shipped]))=2017) 
           AND        (( 
                                            SaleDest.ID_Group)<>10) 
           AND        (( 
                                            QualPack.Quality_Second)<>'NO') 
           AND        (( 
                                            Sales.ID_Dataset)="AC" 
                      OR         ( 
                                            Sales.ID_Dataset)="BU")) 
OR         ((( 
                                            Year([Date_shipped]))=2016) 
           AND        (( 
                                            SaleDest.ID_Group)<>10) 
           AND        (( 
                                            QualPack.Quality_Second)<>'NO') 
           AND        (( 
                                            Sales.ID_Dataset)='AC')) 
GROUP BY   Sales.ID_SaleDest, 
           SaleDest.ID_Group 
ORDER BY   Sales.ID_SaleDest, 
           [Sales]![ID_Dataset] & '-' & Year([Sales]![Date_shipped]) & '-M' & Format(Month([Sales]![Date_shipped]),'00') PIVOT [Sales]![ID_Dataset] & '-' & YEAR([Sales]![Date_shipped]) & '-M' & Format(MONTH([Sales]![Date_shipped]),'00') WITH OWNERACCESS OPTION;
```

The problem is this:

```
PIVOT [Sales]![ID_Dataset] & '-' & YEAR([Sales]![Date_shipped]) & '-M' & Format(MONTH([Sales]![Date_shipped]),'00')
```

How can I pivot this in mssql?

Appriciate your help.

Maja